# Fade-in effect on a drop-down menu doesn't happen always

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, opacity, fade

I want my drop-down menu to have a fade-in effect when mouse-hovered. I've written the following code for that, but the fade-in effect can be observed sometimes only, not always. Code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333333;
}

.header > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
}

.header > li:hover {
  background: #000000;
}

.dropdown ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.dropdown:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header">
  <li class="home">Test</li>
  <li class="dropdown">Dropdown &#10097;
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I think the effect doesn't occur when I unhover and hover over "*Dropdown ❱*" within a second. I'm trying to do this using HTML and CSS only.

How can I achieve what I want?

BTW, How do I create a fade-out effect for the menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display` is not an **animatable** property so you can use [`visibility`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/visibility) instead of `display`.

Here is the list of [animatable-properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333333;
}
.header > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
}
.header > li:hover {
  background: #000000;
}
.dropdown ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  /*display: none;*/
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s;
}
.dropdown:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header">
  <li class="home">Test</li>
  <li class="dropdown">Dropdown &#10097;
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Does CSS support the `//` line comment?

Comment: @CoolGuy You are welcome. No, it is not. It is my fault.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little jQuery to achieve this...

```
$('.header ul').hide();
$('.header li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul').fadeIn();
}, function(){
        $(this).find('ul').fadeOut();
});
```

JSFIDDLE link here: https://jsfiddle.net/omerblink/7n59kew1/

And if you still wanna keep it to just HTML / CSS then just discard the idea of display and use visibility.

```
.dropdown ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s;
}

.dropdown:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

JSFIDDLE link to HTML/CSS solution: https://jsfiddle.net/omerblink/jwd9hLo1/

Comment: Thanks for helping, but the first fiddle with jQuery doesn't show the menu. The second one doesn't use `visibility` and so, when the hover below "_Dropdown ❱_", the drop-down menu appears...